# Open and edit Markdown files with Google Drive iOS App

Tags: ios, applications, data-synchronization, google

Is there a way to open, edit and save back files from the iOS Google Drive app? I've tried some Markdown iOS apps, but I can't seem to open the files from within the Google Drive app. Are there any Markdown apps that can read/write form iOS Google Drive?

Comment: One million downvotes for Google :/

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to find an app that allows you to open markdown from within the the Google Drive app.

However [WriteBox](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/writebox/id575555790?mt=8) allows you to link to your google drive account and then edit and save your markdown files. It also seems designed for markdown note taking (Markdown toolbar and preview) which is nice.

[Write for iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/app/write-for-iphone-beautiful/id587363157?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) also looks promising but I haven't had a chance to try it out yet.